# please name this "pattern" so I can research and learn more

Tags: dns, repository, design-patterns

Some time recently, I heard someone espousing the fact that a domain model should not allow updating the domain objects via properties with a subsequent Save call.  But rather all updates should be done through explicit methods.  Example of how I understand what was said:

Bad Code (that seems pretty normal to me):

```
var x = _repository.GetCustomerByID(5);
x.Firstname = "Travis";
x.Lastname = "Laborde";
_respository.SaveCustomer(x);
```

The Code that I believe this person was pitching would look like:

```
var x = _repository.GetCustomerByID(5);
x.UpdateCustomerName("Travis", "Laborde");
_repository.SaveCustomer(x);
```

I'd like to learn more - is there a name to this pattern so that I can Google it on Bing?

Comment: The "Opinionated Coworker" pattern.

Comment: Are you sure that the problem wasn't the use of a separate "save" call? Asking to keep your interaction with a domain model as single atomic requests is something that to me makes sense for many reasons.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of this pattern having a specific name, but from what you describe, there's a basic practical reason for this:

Writing `x.Firstname = "Travis"` does not let the `x` object know that the `Firstname` value was changed. This makes it hard to implement a `SaveCustomer` function that only uses `UPDATE` on the fields that were changed.

Of course, in a language that does support treating member assignment as a function call (like, say, C# does with its properties), this pattern becomes much less interesting.

Comment: I was starting to read your answer and say: "but, but, but..." Your last paragraph addresses those buts. I work in Delphi and, as in C# (which was largely based on Delphi) properties can have specific getters and setters and so the object could know that the property was changed. In fact, I employ Delphi's property features specifically for this reason in my OPF framework.